# jQuery, the each loop and copying input fields

Tags: jquery, input, each

I have a form that has multiple input fields and i need a button by each input field that will copy the value on that field to a related field next to it. While that may have been really confusing here is a fiddle to help illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/nmfurr/nA37d/234/

```
$(function () {
var i = 0;
var rowID = $('.row').each(function () {
    i++;
    var newID = 'row' + i;
    $(this).attr('id', newID);

});
```

Above is where I am trying to add the ID to each div container around the two input fields. Im assuming this is the best way to target just the two i need.

```
rowID.each(function () {
    var rowID = $(this);
    $("#row1").find(".copy-btn").click(function () {
        var doppelValue = $("input[id^='edit-doppel-field-und-0-value--']");
        var pristineValue = $("input[id^='edit-field-hub']");
        doppelValue.val(pristineValue.val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

this is where I attempt to copy the value. the issue I'm running into is that one copy button is duplicating the first input field and inserting the results into every other input field. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code issue is that you select elements with the same id selector So your query return all inputs on the form instead of the right element : i changed your code and it seems fine in jsfiddle :

```
$(function () {
var i = 0;
var rowID = $('.row').each(function () {
    i++;
    var newID = 'row' + i;
    $(this).attr('id', newID);

});

rowID.each(function () {
    var rowID = $(this);
    rowID.find(".copy-btn").click(function () {
        var doppelValue = rowID.find("input[id^='edit-doppel-field-und-0-value--']");

        var pristineValue = rowID.find("input[id^='edit-field-hub']");

        doppelValue.val(pristineValue.val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out my stupid mistake, works good now!

Comment: *"Good"* is a relative term; there are many inefficiencies in the code, not least the redundant duplicate-each-loop, I'd implore your to examine and chose one of the other approaches... if you are having difficulties seeing the difference just add a comment and I'm sure me or the other author could comment what the lines of code do and why :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the value of the previous input and copy it to the next one using `index`.

```
$(function () {
  $(".copy-btn").click(function () {
    var index = $(":input").index(this);
    var prevInput = $(":input:eq(" + parseInt(index - 1, 10) + ")");
    var nextInput = $(":input:eq(" + parseInt(index + 1, 10) + ")");
    nextInput.val(prevInput.val());
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is your html likely to change? the best way to do this would be simple traversal of the dom...

```
$('.copy-btn').on( "click" , function(e) {

  var selector = "[class^=span]";
  var $this = $(this);
  var $first = $this.closest( selector ).prev( selector ).find("input");
  var $second = $this.closest( selector ).next( selector ).find("input");

  $first.val( $second.val() );

  e.preventDefault(e);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nA37d/240/ <-- there works

Comment: You can also improve your efficiency of the code by giving each `"span-*"` another class such as: `span-first-input` and `span-second-input` or something... the `[class^=]` selector is fairly slow. :)